# Error en Yii2 Model Generator: Table does not exist

Tags: yii2

Quiero ver si alguien sabe cómo solucionar el error. Dice que la tabla no existe pero sí la tengo en la base de datos

[image]

Aquí se encuentra la tabla en la base de datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mario bienvenido al sitio, para agregar información a tu pregunta usa el enlace [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/83749). Te invito a realizar el tour del sitio y revisar cual es la forma adecuada de realizar preguntas, es importante para que obtengas excelentes respuestas, un saludo!

Comment: @Mario, creo que hay algún error en tu conexión a la base de datos ( \config\db.php ).

Comment: no he podido resolver el problema, la conexión de la base de datos si esta bien por que si me registra datos, no encuentro el error quien puede ayudar?

Answer (score 0):

comprueba que tu configuración  tanto la local como la de producción estén bien configuradas  ( sobretodo comprueba la local)

en yii2 advanced estaría en 
common->config-> main.php ( produccion)
common->config-> main-local.php ( local)